# Select data based on values in index pivottable

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I do have a Pivottable and would like to filter the index by values contained in the index. 
I know how to do this for the the values greater 110 in the column "Value"

```
pd_pvt = pivot_table[(pivot_table['Value'] > 110)]
```

How would you select data (bonds only) based on their name in the index?

```
pd_pvt = pivot_table[(index_name['Value'] == "Bonds")]
```

The code above won't work, as the index can't be treated as a column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) if index name is `Value`:

```
pd_pvt = pivot_table[(pivot_table.index.get_level_values('Value') == "Bonds")]
```

Sample:

```
pivot_table = pd.DataFrame({'Value':[200,20,34]}, index=['James','Bonds','Aa'])
pivot_table.index.name = 'Value'
print (pivot_table)
       Value
Value       
James    200
Bonds     20
Aa        34

pd_pvt = pivot_table[(pivot_table.index.get_level_values('Value') == "Bonds")]
print (pd_pvt)
       Value
Value       
Bonds     20
```

You can use position of levels also:

```
pd_pvt = pivot_table[(pivot_table.index.get_level_values(0) == "Bonds")]
print (pd_pvt)
       Value
Value       
Bonds     20
```

Or simple `index`:

```
pd_pvt = pivot_table[(pivot_table.index == "Bonds")]
print (pd_pvt)
       Value
Value       
Bonds     20
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, is there a way to do multiple selections, e.g select the rows for which the index is "James" and "Bonds" ?

Comment: Yes, use `isin` - `pd_pvt = pivot_table[(pivot_table.index.isin(['James','Bonds']))]`

Comment: [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) - docs.